# How to extract the next word in a string after a given word

Tags: regex, perl, split

I want to extract the next word `ball` after `blue`.

For example:

```
I am a blue    #(jjkk, djajd)      ball(apple)
```

I want to extract the next word after `blue`.

Expected output is: `ball`

There can be indefinite white space between the two words.

I have tried:

```
@split_array = split(/\s+/, $');

$next_word = $split_array[1];
```

Comment: Use something like `my ( $substring ) = $string=~ /\bblue\s+(\w+)/;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

(Update #1 via [Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross): Using `\b` in front of `blue` allows matching at the beginning of the string)

```
use strict;

my $input = 'I am a blue ball(apple)';

if ( $input =~ /\bblue\s+(\w+)/ ) {
    my $found = $1;
    print "Word found after word 'blue': $found \n";    
} else {
    print "No word after word 'blue' present\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Word after word 'blue' found: ball
```

Update #2: How to match the second or third word after `blue`?

Change the Regex from `\bblue\s+(\w+)` to `\bblue\s+\w+\s+(\w+)` for the second word.

Correspondingly, use `\bblue\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(\w+)` for the third.

This can be written shorter, but I didn't, to avoid complexity.

Comment: Perhaps replace the `\s+` at the start with `\b` (in case the word is the first word in the string.

Comment: Thanks, that's a more general solution!

Comment: Thanks ...  if want the 2nd or third word after blue what changes I should do?

Comment: I was trying for with the following example but its not working:

use strict;

my $input = 'I am a blue   #(jj)              ball(apple)';

if ( $input =~ /\bblue\s+(\w+)/ ) {
    my $found = $1;
    print "Word found after word 'blue': $found \n";    
} 
elsif ( $input =~ /\bblue\s+\w+\s+(\w+)/ ){
    my $found = $1;
    print "W1ord found after word 'blue': $found \n";
}
else {
    print "No word after word 'blue' present\n";
}

Comment: @JayeshRanjanMajhi: For starters, if your first condition looks for the first word, and the second for the second, the second condition won't ever be matched because the first is already matching. Apart from that, `#(jj)` is not a `word` in the previously used sense, there's non-alphanumeric characters in there. If you want to match these, you could `\S` instead of `\w`. In general, I recommend reading [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to learn more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of regex-based solutions that show you the right way to do this. I thought it would be interesting to see if we could build on your solution.

So you build an array of the words in your string. That works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

$_ = 'I am a blue ball(apple)';

my @split_array = split /\s+/, $_;

say Dumper \@split_array;
```

That gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'I',
          'am',
          'a',
          'blue',
          'ball(apple)'
        ];
```

You then use `$split_array[1]` to get a word. But it's not the right word, of course. `$split_array[1]` is the second element in the array - which is "am".

What you want to do is to walk the array, looking for "blue" and then get the next string. Something like this:

```
foreach (0 .. $#split_array - 1) {
  if ($split_array[$_] eq 'blue') {
    say "The next word is $split_array[$_ + 1]";
  }
}
```

`$#split_array` gives us the index of the last element in `@split_array` (which is 4). We subtract 1 from that as we want the word **after** "blue" and there can't be a word after the last word.

That prints:

```
The next word is ball(apple)
```

Which isn't what you want. So what went wrong? Well, it's your original call to `split`. You're splitting on whitespace and there's no whitespace between "ball" and "apple". So let's split on `\W+` (non-word characters) instead.

Then we get an extra item in our array:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'I',
          'am',
          'a',
          'blue',
          'ball',
          'apple'
        ];
```

And the correct answer.

```
The next word is ball
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to match the string. Here, it is `blue`. It May be at the begining. If not, it is preceded and followed by a space.

```
/(^| )blue /
```

Then, search for the next word. As a word is a group of letters followed by space or end of line:

```
/([\w]+)( |$)/
```

Join them together, and only extract the searched word:

```
/(?:^| )blue ([\w]+)(?: |$)/
```

You may replace "blue" by a variable.

As suggested in the comments below, it is possible to simplify the begining with a `\b` and refine the expression with "one ore more space or tab" (`\s+`):

```
/\b$searched_word\s+([\w]+)(?:\s+|$)/
```

Comment: The `(^| )` can probably be replaced with `\b`. And the literal space you have between the words should probably be `\s+` because the OP said "there can be indefinite white space between the two word".