# Regex - get second word after first match

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse a simple DDL statement. First I'm trying to pull the table name out.
The syntax will be something like 'CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME'

So far I've got this:

```
String line = "CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.T_NAME";
String pattern = ".*?\\bTABLE\\s+(\\w+)\\b.*";
System.out.println(line.replaceFirst(pattern, "$1"));
```

That gives me back "DB_NAME".  How can I get it to give me back "T_NAME"?

I tried following the update in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339128/2751573), but I couldn't get it to work, probably due to my very limited regex skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about sth like this:

```
.*?\\bTABLE\\s+\\w+\\.(\\w+)\\b.*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9K8MUD/1)

It first matches the `TABLE` keyword with `.*?\\bTABLE\\s+`. Then it matches `DB_NAME.` with `\\w+\\.`. Finally it matches and captures `T_NAME` with `(\\w+)`

Comment: You might want to make `\\w+\\.` optional, i.e. `(?:\\w+\\.)?`

Comment: What is the purpose of `\\b`? The `\\w+` will consume all word characters, so the end of that will be nature always be a word boundary.

Comment: If you mean the last \\b, it's because there is more in the actual string after "T_NAME", so I want to stop at the word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small piece of code that will do (using named capturing groups):

```
String line = "CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.T_NAME";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CREATE TABLE (?<database>\\w+)\\.(?<table>\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String database = matcher.group("database"); // DB_NAME
    String table = matcher.group("table"); // T_NAME
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may extract all the string after the `TABLE` into a group and then split with comma to get individual values:

```
String line = "CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.T_NAME";
String pattern = "\\bTABLE\\s+(\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.group(1).split("\\."))); 
    // => [DB_NAME, T_NAME]
}
```

See the [Java  demo](http://ideone.com/KMLhiF).

If you are sure of the incoming format of the string, you might even use

```
"\\bTABLE\\s+(\\S+)"
```

See [another Java demo](http://ideone.com/9mpRGn).

While `\w+(?:\.\w+)*` matches 1+ word chars followed with 0+ repetitions of `.` and 1+ word chars, `\S+` plainly matches 1+ non-whitespace chars.